# Convert decimal to whole number in java

Tags: java, data-conversion

I need to separate the whole number and decimal value. Representing both values as whole numbers.

For example, 1.24 would output:

Whole number: 1
Decimal: 24

Comment: How are you getting the value to be converted? Is the input actually a `double` or a `String` or do you have to read user input, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is String. You can use just use split and separate out the decimal and whole part. Though beware of Floating Point Precision Error.

See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

If you want to be really precise. Use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

```
String decimalString = "46.88999999999999";
String[] decimalSplit = decimalString.split("\\.");
System.out.println("Decimal Number: " + decimalString);
System.out.println("Whole Number: " + decimalSplit[0]);
System.out.println("Decimal Part: " + decimalSplit[1]);

int wholePart = Integer.parseInt(decimalSplit[0]);
double decimalPart = Double.parseDouble("." + decimalSplit[1]);
System.out.println("\nWhole Part: " + wholePart);
System.out.println("Decimal Part: " + decimalPart);
```

**Output:**

```
Decimal Number: 46.88999999999999
Whole Number: 46
Decimal Part: 88999999999999

Whole Part: 46
Decimal Part: 0.88999999999999
```

Comment: @MarcusJones Does this answer work for you?